# In 2-3 player Citadels, can your second character buy a destroyed building using Graveyard?

Tags: citadels

In [Citadels](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/478/citadels) you have a card that permits you to buy buildings ([Graveyard](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/147403/citadels?size=original)) destroyed by the Warlord. But the Warlord cannot buy the destroyed building. In the 2-3 players variant you select 2 characters.

**Can your alter ego buy the destroyed card then?**

Comment: you wouldn't by chance be referring to Bruno Faidutti's city building card game Citadels, would you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Machiavelli, a.k.a. [Citadels](http://www.jinx.com/content/games/Citadels.pdf), has a purple building called Cemetary/Graveyard. The **Warlord** or (Condotaire) is not allowed to buy the destroyed building. You don't really have an alter ego, you have two turns during each round. You can only destroy a building during your **Warlord** turn, and during that turn you are the Warlord and will not be able to use the **Graveyard/Cemetary** ability.

> **Graveyard** - When the Warlord destroys a district, you may pay one gold to take the destroyed district into your hand. You may not do this if you are the Warlord.
>
> In a two- or three-player game, all players play with two characters each. The game is played normally, except that each player has two turns each round (one turn for each character). Players do not have to separate their gold or their districts between their characters, as the players still only have one city.
>
> Each character has a special ability, also called its power. You may use your character’s
> power once during your turn.

Comment: Thx for clearing this out.

Comment: Good question, and good answer!