# How does the graveyard work in citadels?

Tags: citadels

Does the graveyard/cemetery card allow a player to take any destroyed building/district (i.e. including other players destroyed districts) into their hand or can they only redeem their own detroyed districts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/291957/two-questions-graveyard), you can take any district that has been destroyed, so long as you were [not the Warlord](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/in-2-3-player-citadels-can-your-second-character-buy-a-destroyed-building-using) (you can't take a district you just destroyed), and the Graveyard was not the card destroyed.

> 1) Can the player owning the Graveyard claim another palyer’s District just destroyed (e.g. Palyer A destroys Player B’s Observatory and Player C, who owns the Graveyard, spends 1 Gold to claim the Observatory for himself) ?
>   **Answer: Yes**